# BATCHNORM toward an axis in pytorch

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

what is the equivalence keras batch normalization layer of

```py
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1, input_shape=(28,28,1))
```

in pytorch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079783/difference-between-keras-batchnormalization-and-pytorchs-batchnorm2d

Comment: Refer the official Pytorch docs for normalization layers [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#normalization-layers)